# Remove XML Node from a file loaded using PHP filesystem

Tags: php, regex, xml, preg-replace

I have an XML file that's read using PHP's `file_get_contents` so other changes can be done to it.

I need to find and remove the nodes `<BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>`...`<BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>` (not just those two lines, but what's between the entire node) in the entire file.

Since the file is already loaded using `file_get_contents` I'd like to do this without having to load the file again using `simpleXML`, or an XML parser or any other method (like DOM).

The node does not have a specific parent and appears randomly.

The XML file is exported from a Business Accounting Software.

Any idea on how to achieve this? Maybe using a Regular Expression to do a search and replace or something like that?

I've been trying to do this using a regular expression and preg_replace, but just can't get things to work.

[Here's just a portion of the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rFo_M_z0Nttv7YaIbREAqCjpmKFPQhd4). The original runs to 10K+ lines.

This should have worked but doesn't

`preg_replace('/^\<BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST\>(.*?)\<\BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST\>$/ism','', $newXML);`

I'm trying to do this without using any HTML/XML parser.

Comment: Do **not** use RegEx'es to change XML files. Use `lxml` or some other XML parser instead.

Comment: @zx485 ... `lxml` is a Python library, not PHP. OP should use DOMDocument or SimpleXML classes.

Comment: Of course you're right. My apologies for this mistake.

Answer (score -1):

There's probably a better way to do it, but this will work

```
// get your file as a string 
$yourXML = file_get_contents($file) ;

$posStart = stripos($yourXML,'<BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>') ;
$posEnd = stripos($yourXML,'</BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>') + strlen('</BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST>') ;

$newXML = substr($yourXML,0,$posStart) . substr($yourXML,$posEnd) ;
```